# Teradata Store multiple line value like address in a single column

Tags: teradata

Which data type is appropriate to store address details?
How to specifiy new line character while inserting data into this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly discourage you from storing your address details in a single column unless it is being provided to you from the source system in this manner.

Address details should be stored in separate atomic fields allowing for multiple address lines, city, state, postal code, and ZIP+4 (United States). This will provide you the most flexibility and make cleansing of address information using a third-party tool much easier should the need arise later.

```
-- To store a CR/LF in Teradata
SELECT 'A' || '0D0A'xc || 'B';
```

Comment: any recommended data type for such data?

Comment: I would suggest VARCHAR for fields greater than 10 characters and CHAR for fields less than or equal to 10 characters.

Comment: Can VARCHAR store CR/LF character or we need to use VARBYTE for that?

Comment: Yes, you can store non-printable characters in a VARCHAR data type such as CR, LF, and TAB.